# ImageView.setImageResource is not displaying correct drawable

Tags: java, android, view, imageview, drawable

I have this app, it's basically a 'make fun' app I made with a person's face and the ability to either shoot it with a pistol, automatic rifle, or grenade (more weapons to come :-)).

I have a Weapon class, with the following code. (I'm pretty new to java so forgive me if I failed to follow proven ways, or do things as efficiently as I should)

```
public class Weapon {
    // Parent
    public static MainActivity ma;

    // Constants
    public static final int BULLET_WIDTH = 97;
    public static final int BULLET_HEIGHT = 92;
    public static final int EXPLOD_WIDTH = 299;
    public static final int EXPLOD_HEIGHT = 237;
    public static final int PISTOL = 0;
    public static final int RIFLE = 1;
    public static final int GRENADE = 2;

    protected static int[] position = {0, 0};
    protected static RelativeLayout rl = null;
    protected static MediaPlayer mp;

    // Protected stuff
    // Object variables.
    protected int type;
    protected int drawableEffect;
    protected int soundEffect;

    // Functionals
    protected ImageView effectImage;

    public void equipWeapon() {
        // Clear any existing listeners and assign a new one.
        MainActivity.mainImage.setOnTouchListener(null);
        MainActivity.mainImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Which weapon are we using?
                switch (type) {
                case Weapon.PISTOL:
                case Weapon.GRENADE:
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // Fire the weapon.
                    fireWeapon(v, event);
                }
                case Weapon.RIFLE:
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // This doesn't work ???
                        // Fire the weapon.
                        fireWeapon(v, event);
                    }
                }

                // perfomClick needed.
                return v.performClick();
            }

        });
    }

    public void fireWeapon(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Reference the layout.
        Weapon.rl = (RelativeLayout)Weapon.ma.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        // Define properties.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      

        // Get the touch position.
        Weapon.position[0] = (int)event.getX() - ((type == Weapon.PISTOL || type ==     Weapon.RIFLE) ? Weapon.BULLET_WIDTH:Weapon.EXPLOD_WIDTH);
        Weapon.position[1] = (int)event.getY() - ((type == Weapon.PISTOL || type ==     Weapon.RIFLE) ? Weapon.BULLET_HEIGHT:Weapon.EXPLOD_HEIGHT);

        // Set the position.
        lp.setMargins(Weapon.position[0], Weapon.position[1], 0, 0);
        effectImage.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Add the view to the layout.
        Weapon.rl.addView(effectImage, lp);

        // Play the sound.
        Weapon.mp.seekTo(0);
        Weapon.mp.start();

        // Reload
        reload();
    }

    public void reload() {
        // Create the ImageView
        this.effectImage = new ImageView(Weapon.ma);
        this.effectImage.setImageResource(this.drawableEffect);
    }
}
```

And I have a Pistol class which extends Weapon

```
public class Pistol extends Weapon {

    public Pistol() {
        // First save the type.
        this.type = Weapon.PISTOL;

        // Fetch the sound effect and image.
        this.soundEffect = R.raw.gunshot;
        this.drawableEffect = R.drawable.bullet_hole1;

        // Create the media player and initialize the sound.
        Weapon.mp = MediaPlayer.create(Weapon.ma, this.soundEffect);

        // Create the ImageView
        this.effectImage = null;
        this.effectImage = new ImageView(Weapon.ma);
        this.effectImage.setImageResource(this.drawableEffect);
    }
}
```

As well as a Rifle class extending Weapon

```
public class Rifle extends Weapon {

    public Rifle() {
        // First save the type.
        this.type = Weapon.RIFLE;

        // Fetch the sound effect and image.
        this.soundEffect = R.raw.gunshot;
        this.drawableEffect = R.drawable.bullet_hole1;

        // Create the media player and initialize the sound.
        Weapon.mp = MediaPlayer.create(Weapon.ma, this.soundEffect);

        // Create the ImageView
        this.effectImage = null;
        this.effectImage = new ImageView(Weapon.ma);
        this.effectImage.setImageResource(this.drawableEffect);
    }
}
```

finally, I have a Grenade class extending, yep you guessed it, Weapon as well.

```
public class Grenade extends Weapon {

    public Grenade() {
        // First save the type.
        this.type = Weapon.GRENADE;

        // Fetch the sound effect and image.
        this.soundEffect = R.raw.grenade;
        this.drawableEffect = R.drawable.boom;

        // Create the media player and initialize the sound.
        Weapon.mp = MediaPlayer.create(Weapon.ma, this.soundEffect);

        // Create the ImageView
        this.effectImage = new ImageView(Weapon.ma);
        this.effectImage.setImageResource(this.drawableEffect);
    }
}
```

I have buttons in the main view which I have registered onClick listeners to so you can switch weapons to your liking.. Here is one for example:

```
grenadeButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.grenadeButton);
    grenadeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MainActivity.this.weapon != Weapon.GRENADE) {
                // Change the background color.
                resetButtons();
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_selected);

                // Change weapons.
                MainActivity.this.currentWeapon = equipWeapon(Weapon.GRENADE);
            }           
        }
    });
```

and the equip weapon method in MainActivity.

```
public Weapon equipWeapon(int type) {
    Weapon weapon = null;
    switch (type) {
    case Weapon.PISTOL:
        weapon = new Pistol();
        break;
    case Weapon.RIFLE:
        weapon = new Rifle();
        break;
    case Weapon.GRENADE:
        weapon = new Grenade();
        break;
    }

    // Play a sound and save changes.
    MainActivity.this.weapon = type;
    MainActivity.mp.seekTo(0);
    MainActivity.mp.start();

    return weapon;
}
```

Now, I appreciate you taking the time to review all this code. I know that's a lot to digest for what I'm assuming is a simple issue.  I'm also aware of the rules of this forum and I have attempted to search for this issue already, but I'm not sure if I was using the right queries, as I did not find anything related to this issue.

Here we go:

When you start the app, the pistol is automatically equipped so you can start shooting immediately.  It shoots fine, I get a bullet noise, and bullet holes all over the picture of the person's face ^_^.  The rifle works fine as well (but it uses the same noise and graphic as the pistol, so it could very well be failing as well. Refer below).

When I switch to the grenade, I here a lovely explosion sound, but the image displayed is still a bullet hole and not an explosion.. I have no earthly idea how to fix this and I am stumped..

When I create the grenade object I specifically assign the drawable resource to the instance variable...

```
this.drawableEffect = R.drawable.boom;
```

Yet it still displays R.drawable.bullet_hole1....

Please let me know if you need more information and ask any questions you need to..

Thank you for your time..

Comment: What's with the down votes?  I couldn't figure it out so I came here... I followed guidelines for asking a question on here (Explained the situation thoroughly, provided code, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so stupid.....

```
MainActivity.equipWeapon
```

wasn't calling

```
Weapon.equipWeapon....
```

So the weapon wasn't changing... Oy' vey...